# Adding information between and after nodes

Tags: nodes, labels, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to compose a semantic tableaux for three days and I can not seem to figure out the last few missing pieces.

Below is my, perhaps not the most elegant, code that I have come up with so far. There are operations missing in nodes that have two siblings and split because the `\edge[midway,right]` doesn't behave the way I want it to in those cases.

```
\begin{figure}[]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,
        every tree node/.style={inner sep=0.0625cm, circle, draw},
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=-50pt},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=10pt}, 
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=2pt}, 
        level 4/.style={sibling distance=10pt}, 
        level 5/.style={sibling distance=18pt}, 
        level 6/.style={sibling distance=12pt}, 
        bold/.style={font=\bf},
        level distance=40pt,
        scale=0.9,
        nodot/.style={draw,fill},
        edge from parent/.style=
        {draw,
            edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                -- +(0,-20pt)
                -| (\tikzchildnode)}}
    ]
    %end markup
    \Tree [.\node[ label=left:{$(\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)))\leftrightarrow s,p\rightarrow (q\wedge r)$}] (root)  {};   %level 0
            [.\node[label=left:{$p\wedge r$}] {};%level 1
                \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\wedge L$};
                [.\node[label=left:{$q,r$}] {};                     
                    [.\node[label=left:{$\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)),s$}] {};
                        \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg L$};
                        [.\node[label=right:{$p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)$}] {};
                            [.\node[label=right:{$p$}]  {};]
                            [.\node[label=right:{{$\circ q\vee\neg r$}}] {};
                                \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\vee R$};
                                [.\node[label=right:{$q,\neg r$}] {};]          
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [.\node[label=right:{$\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)),s$}] {};
                        \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg R$};
                        [.\node[label=left:{$p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)$}] {};
                            \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\wedge L$};
                            [.\node[label=left:{$p,q\vee\neg r$}] {};
                                [.\node[label=left:{$q$}] {};]
                                [.\node[label=left:{$\neg r$}] {};
                                    \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg R$};
                                    [.\node[label=right:{$r$}] {}; ]                                        
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [.\node[label=right:{$p$}] {};%level 1
                [.\node[label=left:{$s,\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r))$}] {};
                    \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg L$};
                    [.\node[label=right:{$p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)$}] {};
                        [.\node[label=right:{$p$}] {}; ]
                        [.\node[label=right:{$p\vee\neg r$}] {};
                            \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\vee R$};
                            [.\node[label=right:{$q,\neg r$}] {};
                                \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg R$};
                                [.\node[label=left:{$r$}] {};]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
                [.\node[label=right:{$\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)),s$}] {}; 
                    \edge node[midway,right, bold] {$\neg R$};
                    [.\node[label=left:{$p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)$}] {};
                        \edge node[midway,right, bold] {$\wedge L$};
                        [.\node[label=left:{$p,q\vee\neg r$}] {};]          
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the output my code generates. Black is what the code does, and red is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I have tried to add more nodes and tried to position them absolutely, tried the edge on the splitting paths, looked for a way to add more labels.

I have come to a point I can't see the trees through the forest anymore and have decided to ask for some help. All help is appreciated. (Open to new packages and suggestions too)

Comment: Some of them can be done using pos=1.5 from above.  For example, \edge node[midway,right,bold] {$\wedge L$} node[pos=1.5,right,bold,red] {$\neg L$};  However, for others you will need to find (or create) named coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned the possibility of using an alternative package. You also mentioned a forest, somewhere along the line. Perhaps if you can't see the forest for the trees, you should just draw a forest instead.

This solution is based on the current version of **forest**. I defines a style `derivation tree` based on your current code. It also defines `circular empty nodes` which just tells `forest` to draw circles for empty nodes. I thought it might be useful to keep this separate from the code for `derivation tree`.

In addition to the various keys which can be used to format a tree from the **forest** package, you can use the ***TikZ*** styles `fork label` and `rule label` to determine the formatting of the labels for the rules of inference:

```
\tikzset{
  fork label/.style={},
  rule label/.style={},
}
```

`rule label` affects rules which don't branch. `fork label` affects those which do.

These correspond to two ***forest*** keys, `fork label` and `rule label` which can be used to specify labels for branching and non-branching rules within the tree. `fork label` is a custom **forest** option:

```
declare autowrapped toks={fork label}{},
```

which is used in specifying the edge path:

```
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-20pt) node [midway, anchor=west, right, fork label] {$\forestoption{fork label}$} -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
```

The first occurrence of `fork label` here is the TikZ style. The second is the `\forestoption{fork label}`. `rule label` doesn't require a custom option as we can use the existing options and just create a **forest** style:

```
    rule label/.style={
      edge label={node [pos=.5, right, anchor=west, rule label] {$##1$}},
    },
```

Both `rule label` and `fork label` wrap their contents in a maths environment, so there is no need for `$...$` signs in these cases.

In addition `left label` will format a node label on the left. `right label` will format one on the right. I should mention that these are not, technically, node labels. They are, in fact, additional nodes in the tree:

```
    left label/.style={
      before typesetting nodes={
        insert before={[{##1}, no edge, before drawing tree={x+=7.5pt}]}
      }
    },
    right label/.style={
      before typesetting nodes={
        insert after={[{##1}, no edge, before drawing tree={x-=7.5pt}]}
      }
    },
```

I did it this way so that **forest** rather than I would get the job of calculating appropriate sibling spacings based on the content of the nodes within the tree. This way, the tree is spaced appropriately based on its content without, hopefully, much need for intervention when the tree is specified.

To use both the `derivation tree` and the `circular empty nodes` styles, just drop them into the preamble of a `forest` environment:

```
\begin{forest}
  derivation tree,
  circular empty nodes,
```

This will format the tree appropriately and enable the additional options and styles. You can then say, for example:

```
  [, left label={$p,q\lor \lnot p$},
    [, fork label=\lor L, right label={$\lnot p$}
      [, rule label=\lor R, left label={$p$}
      ]
    ]
    [, left label={$q$}
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

to produce:

[image: simple case]

This greatly simplifies the specification of trees and makes them easier to read from the source.

The translation of your original code, with the additional nodes in red produces this result:

[image: complex case]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  fork label/.style={},
  rule label/.style={},
}
\forestset{
  derivation tree/.style={
    declare autowrapped toks={fork label}{},
    for tree={
      l sep+=15pt,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-20pt) node [midway, anchor=west, right, fork label] {$\forestoption{fork label}$} -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      if level=0{}{
        if={equal(n_children("!u"),1)}{
          before packing={calign with current}
        }{
          if n=1{
            before packing={
              !u.calign primary child/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{n}
            }
          }{
            before packing={
              !u.calign secondary child/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{n}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    rule label/.style={
      edge label={node [pos=.5, right, anchor=west, rule label] {$##1$}},
    },
    left label/.style={
      before typesetting nodes={
        insert before={[{##1}, no edge, before drawing tree={x+=7.5pt}]}
      }
    },
    right label/.style={
      before typesetting nodes={
        insert after={[{##1}, no edge, before drawing tree={x-=7.5pt}]}
      }
    },
    before packing={
      for tree={
        tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier ##1}{level},
      }
    }
  },
  circular empty nodes/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        if content={}{circle, draw, anchor=center, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt}{}
      }
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  derivation tree,
  circular empty nodes,
%   /tikz/rule label/.style={text=blue, font=\bfseries\small},
  /tikz/fork label/.style={red},
  [, label=left:{$(\lnot(p\land(q\lor\lnot r)))\leftrightarrow s,p\rightarrow (q\land r)$},
      [, left label={$p\land r$},
          [, left label={$q,r$}, rule label=\land L,
              [, left label={$\lnot(p\land(q\lor\lnot r)),s$},
                [, right label={$p\land(q\lor\lnot r)$}, rule label=\lnot L,
                    [, right label={$p$}
                    ]
                  [, right label={$\circ q\lor\lnot r$}, fork label=\land R
                      [, right label={$q,\lnot r$}, rule label=\lor R,
                      ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [, right label={$\lnot(p\land(q\lor\lnot r)),s$}, fork label=\leftrightarrow L
                  [, left label={$p\land(q\lor\lnot r)$}, rule label=\lnot R,
                      [, left label={$p,q\lor\lnot r$}, rule label=\land L,
                          [, left label={$q$},
                          ]
                          [, left label={$\lnot r$}, fork label=\lor L
                              [, right label={$r$}, rule label=\lnot R,
                              ]
                          ]
                      ]
                  ]
              ]
          ]
        ]
        [, right label={$p$}, fork label=\rightarrow L
          [, left label={$s,\lnot(p\land(q\lor\lnot r))$},
                [, right label={$p\land(q\lor\lnot r)$}, rule label=\lnot L,
                    [, right label={$p$},
                    ]
                    [, right label={$p\lor\lnot r$}, fork label=\lor R
                        [, right label={$q,\lnot r$}, rule label=\lor R,
                            [, left label={$r$}, rule label=\lnot R,
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [, right label={$\lnot(p\land(q\lor\lnot r)),s$}, fork label=\leftrightarrow L
                [, left label={$p\land(q\lor\lnot r)$}, rule label=\lnot R,
                    [, left label={$p,q\lor\lnot r$}, rule label=\land L,
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

If you wished to, you could also configure the style so that `left label` and `right label` used maths mode or to provide the option of specifying derivation rules to the left, as well as to the right. Whether these possibilities are of any use to you is, of course, another matter entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, I gave every tree node a name and consolidated the `midway` nodes into one `\path` at the end.  I probably could have come up with a better naming protocol.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,
        every tree node/.style={inner sep=0.0625cm, circle, draw},
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=-50pt},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=10pt}, 
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=2pt}, 
        level 4/.style={sibling distance=10pt}, 
        level 5/.style={sibling distance=18pt}, 
        level 6/.style={sibling distance=12pt}, 
        bold/.style={font=\bf},
        level distance=40pt,
        scale=0.9,
        nodot/.style={draw,fill},
        edge from parent/.style=
        {draw,
            edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode)% note: removed .south
                -- +(0,-20pt)
                -| (\tikzchildnode)}}
    ]
    %end markup
    \Tree [.\node[ label=left:{$(\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)))\leftrightarrow s,p\rightarrow (q\wedge r)$}] (root)  {};   %level 0
            [.\node[label=left:{$p\wedge r$}] (B) {};%level 1
                [.\node[label=left:{$q,r$}] (C) {};                     
                    [.\node[label=left:{$\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)),s$}] (D) {};
                        [.\node[label=right:{$p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)$}] (E) {};
                            [.\node[label=right:{$p$}] (F) {};]
                            [.\node[label=right:{{$\circ q\vee\neg r$}}] (G) {};
                                [.\node[label=right:{$q,\neg r$}] (H) {};]          
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [.\node[label=right:{$\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)),s$}] (I) {};
                        [.\node[label=left:{$p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)$}] (J) {};
                            [.\node[label=left:{$p,q\vee\neg r$}] (K) {};
                                [.\node[label=left:{$q$}] (L) {};]
                                [.\node[label=left:{$\neg r$}] (M) {};
                                    [.\node[label=right:{$r$}] (N) {}; ]                                        
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [.\node[label=right:{$p$}] (O) {};%level 1
                [.\node[label=left:{$s,\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r))$}] (P) {};
                    [.\node[label=right:{$p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)$}] (Q) {};
                        [.\node[label=right:{$p$}] (R) {}; ]
                        [.\node[label=right:{$p\vee\neg r$}] (S) {};
                            [.\node[label=right:{$q,\neg r$}] (T) {};
                                [.\node[label=left:{$r$}] (U) {};]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
                [.\node[label=right:{$\neg(p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)),s$}] (V) {}; 
                    [.\node[label=left:{$p\wedge(q\vee\neg r)$}] (W) {};
                        [.\node[label=left:{$p,q\vee\neg r$}] (X) {};]          
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
  \path (root) -- +(0pt,-20pt) node[midway,right,bold] {$\rightarrow L$}
     (B) -- (C)  node[midway,right,bold]  {$\wedge L$}
     (C) -- +(0pt,-20pt) node[midway,right,bold] {$\rightarrow L$}
     (D) -- (E) node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg L$}
     (E) -- +(0pt,-20pt) node[midway,right,bold] {$\wedge R$}
     (G) -- (H) node[midway,right,bold] {$\vee R$}
     (I) -- (J) node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg R$}
     (J) -- (K) node[midway,right,bold] {$\wedge L$}
     (K) -- +(0,-20pt) node[midway,right,bold] {$\vee L$}
     (M) -- (N) node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg R$}
     (O) -- +(0,-20pt) node[midway,right,bold] {$\leftrightarrow L$}
     (P) -- (Q) node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg L$}
     (Q) -- +(0,-20pt) node[midway,right,bold] {$\wedge R$}
     (S) -- (T) node[midway,right,bold] {$\vee R$}
     (T) -- (U) node[midway,right,bold] {$\neg R$}
     (V) -- (W) node[midway,right, bold] {$\neg R$}
     (W) -- (X) node[midway,right, bold] {$\wedge L$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree]